# VS 2019 is looking for wrong assembly version of packages

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light, nuget-package, visual-studio-2019, .net-core-3.0

I'm creating my first project using `.Net Core` but I'm having some issues getting two `Nuget` packages working probably.

When trying to debug the app, I get the following two errors:

`Could not load file or assembly 'GalaSoft.MvvmLight, Version=5.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0ffbc31322e9d308'. The system cannot find the file specified.`

`Could not load file or assembly 'GongSolutions.WPF.DragDrop, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0ffbc31322e9d308'. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Now, here's what it says for these packages under the solution explorer:

[image]
[image]

It's showing different versions than what the errors are showing. I searched through every file in my project and the only places I found the wrong versions showing was in my project's `.deps.json` file, which shows the following:

```
{
  "runtimeTarget": {
    "name": ".NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0",
    "signature": ""
  },
  "compilationOptions": {},
  "targets": {
    ".NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0": {
      "TestProject/1.0.0": {
        "dependencies": {
          "MvvmLightLibsStd10": "5.4.1.1",
          "gong-wpf-dragdrop": "2.1.0",
        },
        "runtime": {
          "TestProject.dll": {}
        }
      },
      "gong-wpf-dragdrop/2.1.0": {
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netcoreapp3.0/GongSolutions.WPF.DragDrop.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "2.0.0.0",
            "fileVersion": "2.1.0.2"
          }
        }
      },
      "MvvmLightLibsStd10/5.4.1.1": {
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netstandard1.0/GalaSoft.MvvmLight.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "5.4.1.0",
            "fileVersion": "5.4.1.0"
          }
        }
      },
```

I've tried changing the above to match the right versions, but it didn't change anything.

What else I've tried:

- Uninstalling and Reinstalling the pacakages
- Restarting Visual Studio

I did notice that the wrong packages do exist in other folders under: `C:\Users\myname\.nuget\packages` but they don't match the path that visual studio is showing me for the actual `.dlls` I'm using.

Some notes that might be useful:

The entire solution contains two projects: a `WPF Windows Application` which contains a single `Window` and a `WPF Class Library`, which has a `UserControl` hosted inside the wpf application project.

The `Class Library` is what contains the nuget packages.

Both projects are targeting `.NET Core 3.0`.

Update: I've tried putting the following inside a `<PropertyGroup>` tag in both my `.csproj` files:

```
<RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>
<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
<GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
```

None of them worked.

Comment: Avoid being misled by the version number misery, the diagnostic is "file not found", not "wrong version".  Look in the bin\Debug directory of your WPF project, expectation is that these DLLs are indeed missing.  Common .NETCore scourge, google ".net core copy dependencies" to find the workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The DLLs are actually there thought. I set the output folder for both the control project and the executable to a separate folder, and went into the .csproj files to make sure `<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>` was set to `true` for both.

Comment: I have exactly same issue. Have you been able to find solution to this?

Comment: I sort of got it working but I honestly can't remember what I did. I've given up on .net core for now. If you're using the same two packages, the exact version of gong-wpf-dragdrop on nuget I used is 2.1.0 published 9/25/19. The mvvmlightlibsstd10 is version 5.4.1.1 published on 9/11/18.